# Unable to create a null constant value of type XX.XX Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am using EF. A parent table `CUSTOMER` and a relational table `CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_TERM`.
I want to get result with following approach.

```
var result = (from x in EntitiesContext.CUSTOMERS
              select new
              {
                  CustomerId = x.CUSTOMERID,
                  PaymentTerms = x.PAYMENTTERMID > 0 ?
                  new PaymentTermBo
                  {
                      PaymentTermId = (decimal)x.PAYMENTTERMID,
                      Discount = (decimal)x.CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_TERM.DISCOUNT
                  }
                  : null,
              }).ToList();
```

I got following error for above code.

> Unable to create a null constant value of type PaymentTermBo Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

I really want to use this approach "Want to put if condition for object to fill".
But when use following approach, it works.

```
var result = (from x in EntitiesContext.CUSTOMERS
              select new
              {
                  CustomerId = x.CUSTOMERID,
                  PaymentTerms = new PaymentTermBo
                  {
                      PaymentTermId = x.PAYMENTTERMID > 0 ? (decimal)x.PAYMENTTERMID : 0,
                      Discount = x.PAYMENTTERMID > 0 ? (decimal)x.CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_TERM.DISCOUNT : 0
                  }
              }).ToList();
```

But i want to use first approach as i have complex tables and many columns,  do not want to fill all the values by putting if condition for each value as it will slow down the query.

Comment: use Nullable type

Comment: I used Nullable type but got same error. also user (PaymentTermBo)Null but same error.

Comment: EF has to compute a sql for the expression, but can't create a null value of PaymentTermBo to put in the result set. Try adding another .ToList() before that check so the projection is done in memory instead.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Sir can you please explain your point according to my code? i mean implement your point in my code so i can understand your point.

Comment: everything before the .ToList() has to be converted to sql by EF, especially the x.PAYMENTTERMID > 0 ? [...] : null. This means EF has to "create" a null value to be materialized afterwards, which is not supported because the structure is not "flat". To fix this, you can tell ef to materialize sooner (i.e. let selection run in memory - linq to entities - by changing the source from EntitiesContext.CUSTOMERS to EntitiesContext.CUSTOMERS.ToList()) so the rest will be done in memory instead of on database level.

Comment: @ DevilSuichiro if we do EntitiesContext.CUSTOMERS.ToList()) then it will again take the long time to execute the query, the basic purpose of this to reduce the query time.

Comment: Is there any way to manage the code in this way


 new PaymentTermBo
                  {
                      PaymentTermId = (decimal)x.PAYMENTTERMID,
                      Discount = (decimal)x.CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_TERM.DISCOUNT
                  }
                  : null,

We can assign value or null in select new statement